# How to clean up RxJava fire and forget subscriptions?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have fire and forget operations that don't take very long, but long enough that I wanted to run them in the background reactively. There lifetime is basically while the connection to the server exists or 10 seconds has passed. I don't know how to store these so that I can clean them out efficiently while still maintaining the correct life cycle.

```
Subscription fireAndForget = service.doSomething()
                                    .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .subscribe( () -> {
                                        otherService.doAction()
                                    }, (e) -> { Log.e("error", e) });
// what do I do with fireAndForget???

// If I use a CompositeSubscription
subscriptions.add(fireAndForget) // how does it get removed????
```

I could have a CompositeSubscription on my connection that keep holds of them, but then how do I clear them out when the operation is finished? Should I even bother clearing out a CompositeSubscription when the subscription unsubscribes? I am relatively new to Rx so I am not sure if I am just trying to do something Rx wasn't meant to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hint: Fire and **forget**

You are not forgetting if you keep a subscription around. Just call subscribe and move on.

```
service.doSomething()
    .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe( () -> {
        otherService.doAction()
    }
```

**Edit**: Garbage collection.

Unless you do something very strange (like using WeakReference), your executing code in `doSomething` will prevent the entire chain from being garbage collected.

Think of RxJava like an onion, every time you transform an observable (map, doOnNext, etc.) a new Observable is created that wraps the old observable like an onion.

For each transformation a new `Subscriber` is created that passes on the callbacks (onNext, onCompleted, onError) to the next `Subscriber` in the chain.

The main reason for a `Subscription` is so that you can call `unsubscribe`. There are two reason you may want to call unsubscribe.

1. You have a hot observable. Basically this observable will emit values forever. An example could be an observable the emits the time every 30 seconds. You can call `unsubscribe` when you are no longer interested the time value.
2. You want to cancel a long operation. Lets say you are loading a webpage from to display to the user, if the user presses back, you want to cancel the loading (you no longer care about the results).

**Example** Source Code for map operation

Map simply calls `lift` with an `OperatorMap` as the argument. Lift creates a new `Observable` based upon an `Operator`, it can be ignored for the time being.

```
public final <R> Observable<R> map(Func1<? super T, ? extends R> func) {
    return lift(new OperatorMap<T, R>(func));
}
```

`OperatorMap` creates a new `Subscriber` that mostly just passes calls into whatever `Subscriber` it is given. This could be the `Subscriber` you pass into `subscribe` or a `Subscriber` created by another `map` transformation, it does not really matter.

```
public final class OperatorMap<T, R> implements Operator<R, T> {

    private final Func1<? super T, ? extends R> transformer;

    public OperatorMap(Func1<? super T, ? extends R> transformer) {
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super R> o) {
        return new Subscriber<T>(o) {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                o.onCompleted();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                o.onError(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(T t) {
                try {
                    o.onNext(transformer.call(t));
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Exceptions.throwOrReport(e, this, t);
                }
            }

        };
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh... That seems easy but I am confused. What stops the whole object chain from getting garbage collected?

Comment: In short, the executing code in `doSomething` see my updated answer for more detail.

Comment: What prevents the whole object chain from getting garbage collection is the `Subscription` that is being held. (as cyroxis said: "You are not forgetting if you keep a subscription around.")
Without the `Subscription`, the data becomes unreachable(it's not linked to other data) and gets garbage collected.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt You do not need to keep the `Subscription` to prevent garbage collection. The executing code in `doSomething()` (does not really matter what thread) has a reference to your `Subscriber` and will call it.

Comment: That doesn't work with asynchronous code where the `Observable` is still active when the method that calls `doSomething()` is exited. Upon exiting the calling method, garbage collection could destroy the Subscription/Observer at any point before it is finished.

Comment: Addendum: it might depend on whether the stream source of service.doSomething() can be garbage-collected or not. For example returning `Observable.just()` vs returning a `PublishSubject` that is kept as a reference somewhere.

Comment: 1. Executing code (just or aync operation) will not be garbage collected. 2. Executing code has a reference through the observable chain to your subscribe method. Given those two things how would the chain be garbage collected?

Answer (score 1):

Forget about to get the subscription unless you want to know if is still subscribe or not. By design Observable will unsubcribe the observer onComplete. Then since the instance is not used anymore, the GC at some point will remove it.

just refactor your code:

```
    service.doSomething().timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                .subscribe( () -> {
                                    otherService.doAction()
                                }, (e) -> { Log.e("error", e) });
```

You can see examples about how subscribe works here.

https://github.com/politrons/reactive/blob/master/src/test/java/rx/observables/creating/ObservableSubscription.java

Answer (score 0):

Your `CompositeSubscription` should be stored in any parent object of your liking. This will tie the lifecycle of the `CompositeSubscription`'s parent to the `CompositeSubscription` itself:
When the parent object becomes unreachable, the `CompositeSubscription` with the parent object will both be garbage-collected.

Also, if the parent of the `CompositeSubscription` has lifecycle methods such as `onStop()`, you could manually unsubscribe the `CompositeSubscription`. Similarly, if you have a lifecycle method available such as `onStart()` or `onResume()`, you could subscribe (again) there.

[This page](http://www.dynatrace.com/en/javabook/how-garbage-collection-works.html) might give you more info about garbage collection.